# How test onUpdate method of my widget not waiting 30min

Tags: android, widget, onupdate

After 3 days learning widgets, I finally understand about setOnClickPendingIntent,RemoteViews... and I've done my widget. It has been done with help of a lot of tutorials. But now I'd like to test if it works. As I read, the minimum update rate is 30min. And the other way is using AlarmManager. But I cant find any example with AlarmManager. 
After I waited 30min,  nothing happened. I changed some things and still waiting, that it changes...

Is there any way to test it faster?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <appwidget-provider
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="65dip"
    android:minHeight="30dip"

    android:updatePeriodMillis="180000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/main" />
```

CountWidget

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class CountWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    private static final int[] IMAGES = { R.drawable.die_1, R.drawable.die_2,
            R.drawable.die_3, R.drawable.die_4, R.drawable.die_5,
            R.drawable.die_6 };
    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "ActionReceiverWidget";
    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE = "ConfigureWidget";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        ComponentName me = new ComponentName(context, CountWidget.class);

        appWidgetManager
                .updateAppWidget(me, buildUpdate(context, appWidgetIds));

        // обновляем виджет
        // appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);

    }

    private RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        // Создаем новый RemoteViews
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.main);

        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.left_die, IMAGES[(int) (Math
                .random() * 6)]);

        // Подготавливаем Intent для Broadcast
        Intent configIntent = new Intent(context,
                CountWhatYouWantActivity.class);
        configIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE);

        // создаем наше событие
        PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                0, configIntent, 0);

        // регистрируем наше событие

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.left_die, configPendingIntent);
        return (remoteViews);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
private static Intent updateIntent = new Intent();
{
    updateIntent.setAction(WidgetProvider.ACTION_WIDGET_UPDATE);
    updateIntent.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse(WidgetProvider.URI_SCHEME + "://widget/id/"), ""));
}

private void setAlarm(Context context) {
    PendingIntent newPending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, updateIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Time now = new Time();
    now.setToNow();
    long nowMillis = now.toMillis(false);
    long nextMillis = ((nowMillis / 60000) * 60000) + 60000;

    AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    // set the repeating real time clock minute synchronised alarm
    alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextMillis, 60 * 1000, newPending);

}
```

Call the setAlarm() function in your onEnabled() method of the AppWidgetProvider.

Comment: Don't forget to call [AlarmManager.cancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel(android.app.PendingIntent)) in the onDisabled() method of your AppWidgetProvider either, or your alarm will continue to tick off even after the last widget has been removed!

Answer (score -1):

I have written an answer here [Android: How do I force the update of all widgets of a particular kind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304387/android-how-do-i-force-the-update-of-all-widgets-of-a-particular-kind) that allows your widget to be updated whenever it is clicked. This can give you greater control of when an update is performed.

Answer (score -6):

You should simply modify your "widget.xml" file:

```
android:updatePeriodMillis="15000"
```

This will cause it to fire in 15 seconds.  The number is in millseconds, ie, 1000ms=1sec...