# Widget should show actual prefs

Tags: android, android-widget, sharedpreferences

I use DefaultSharedPreferences in my app. And I want create a widget which will toggle one of my preference. I done the widget. And it's doing what I want, but if I change this preference from other activity, widget dosen't update.

```
public class WidgetReceiver extends AppWidgetProvider {
    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_TOGGLE = "ActionToggle";

    public void onUpdate( Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds ) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews( context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_on_off );

        boolean state = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( context ).getBoolean( "serviceOn", true );
        if( state )
            remoteViews.setImageViewResource( R.id.widgetImage, R.drawable.ic_widget );
        else
            remoteViews.setImageViewResource( R.id.widgetImage, R.drawable.ic_widget_dark );

        Intent intent = new Intent( context, WidgetReceiver.class );
        intent.setAction( ACTION_WIDGET_TOGGLE );
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( context, 0, intent, 0 );
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent( R.id.widgetImage, pendingIntent );

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget( appWidgetIds, remoteViews );
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if( AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED.equals( action )) {
            final int appWidgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt( AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID );
            if ( appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID ) {
                this.onDeleted( context, new int[] { appWidgetId });
            }
        } else {
            if( intent.getAction().equals( ACTION_WIDGET_TOGGLE )) {
                boolean state = !PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( context ).getBoolean( "serviceOn", true );
                Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( context ).edit();
                editor.putBoolean( "serviceOn", state );
                editor.commit();
                ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName( context.getPackageName(), WidgetReceiver.class.getName());
                AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance( context );
                int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);
                onUpdate( context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
            }
            super.onReceive(context, intent);
        }
    }
}
```

How, make it work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you change preference from some activity, there is no reason for widget to update (for its onUpdate() function to be called). What you should do is send intent from activity that  changed preference, intent that will trigger your widget to display new data.
Sending such kind of intent is explained [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304387/android-how-do-i-force-the-update-of-all-widgets-of-a-particular-kind).

Comment: Can You give me an example, please? I don't know how to call widget.onUpdate() from an activity.