# AppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds in activity returns an empty list

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I have an appwidget that I'm trying to update from an activity.

To do that, I need the appwidget id.

I've used `AppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds` but it always returns an empty list.

I also used `AppWidgetManager.getInstalledProviders` to make sure that my `ComponentName` is correct, but still I get an empty list.

I've seen all the other questions about this, but I couldn't find something that worked for me.

Is there another way to solve this? or another way to update the widget?

My code:

```
ComponentName name = new ComponentName(packageName, boardcastReceiverClass);
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
int[] ids = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(name);
if (ids != null && ids.length > 0) {
   getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(getUpdateIntent(ids[0]));
}
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I should mention that my AppWidgetProvider is in a library project. According to the ComponentName I get with `getInstalledProviders`, I used the package name of my app and the class name with the package name of the library.

Comment: share your code where you think the mistake is...

Comment: getAppWidgetIds() will return empty list if user has not enabled/installed your Widget on Home screen...

Comment: @GopalRao yes, I know. I tested it when the widget was on the home screen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can access your widget without knowing id

```
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(this.getPackageName(),Widget.class.getName()), views);
```

This let you access the widget without having to know the 'appWidgetID'. Then in activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnActivate, pendingIntent);

AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(this.getPackageName(), Widget.class.getName()), views);
finish();
```

Comment: This seems like the answer to my question as well, but I am having trouble identifying the parameters. The parameters you mention [appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(this.getPackageName(),Widget.class.getName()), views);], First, is the widget class the widget provider? the widget config? Or a service from the widget? And second, the views, I am not passing in any views objects, to what is the views referring to? What would be an example of a view within a service class?  
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Scratch the views question, I figured out it means remoteViews.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on something similar and here is the simplest way I got it to work.

In your service class put this wherever you want to trigger a widget update:

```
Intent brIntent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
sendBroadcast(brIntent);
```

This will cause the onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) method in your AppWidgetProvider class to be called. Then onRecieve can call code to update the widget. For a sample, here's what I used. I'm merely updating the text of the widget:

```
        //Sample output text
    String text = "My cat's name is wiggles.";
    //get an AppWidgetManager
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    //getComponentName
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
    //get the IDs for all the instances of this widget
    int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
    //update all of the widgets
    for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
        //get any views in this instance of the widget
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        // Set the text
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetField,  text);
        //update the widget with any change we just made
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the app widget ID.. use this below code

onReceive() method use this below code

```
int appWidgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
```

in onUpdate() you get the list of ids already as the parameter!

If you want to update it from activity use this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, [activityname].class);
    intent.setAction("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE");
    int ids[] = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplication()).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(getApplication(), [activityname].class));
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,ids);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: I'm trying to update the widget from an activity, not from the receiver, so I don't have `onReceieve`.