# Broadcast Receiver is taking too long to receive in onReceive() after airplane mode turned off/on

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, airplane-mode

I have created a simple Broadcast Receiver and it working absolutely fine except that if i turned on/off the Air Plane Mode, it is taking nearly 2 minutes to receive the broadcasted messages using onReceive method. Another thing is only this is causing a problem if we launch the application and then if i change Air plane Mode (on/off), Then it taking too long to receive the message.

***If there is Mode change before launching the application it didn't affect the time to receive the message in onReceive method.***

Source code is below.

***AndroidManifest.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.broadcastreceiver"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.broadcastreceiver.BroadcastReceiverActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

       <receiver android:name="MyBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="test.intent.action.QR_CODE_RECEIVER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

***BroadcastReceiverActivity.java***

```
public class BroadcastReceiverActivity extends Activity {

    public static String qrCodeReceiver = "test.intent.action.QR_CODE_RECEIVER";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button broadcastBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.broadcastBtn);
        broadcastBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                //TODO
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("message","Testing");
                intent.setAction(qrCodeReceiver);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
                Log.d("Test","sendBroadcasting the message ::");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

***MyBroadcastReceiver.java***

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //TODO
        Toast.makeText(context, "on receive.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String state = extras.getString("message");
        Log.d("Test", "Inside MyBroadcastReceiver onReceive() state :: "+ state);
        Toast.makeText(context, state,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

***main.xml***

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".BroadcastReceiverActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/broadcastBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:text="Send The BroadCast Message" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Android System, broadcast are processed internally.

Sometimes, due to system loading/ restart/ high runtime, the broadcast receiver gets time to receive some intent

Workaround is, to add Flag FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND to intent sending broadcast

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
```

This will speed up the broadcast delivery much than before in problem scenario

Comment: Kushal How to add this flag to broadcast using manifest? because I want to know whether internet in connected or not very quickly

Comment: From Oreo, there are certain restrictions on manifest based broadcasts, so I would suggest to use this from `java/Kotlin` side dynamically