# Android: Receiving broadcasts late

Tags: android, android-intent

I am sending custom broadcasts from AppWidgetProvider class:

```
intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("packagename.intent.action.SET_VOLUME_STATE");
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and listening for them in BroadcastReceiver class:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals("packagename.intent.action.SET_VOLUME_STATE"))
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

and have also registered the receiver with intent filter in manifest file. The problem is I am receiving the broadcast intent very late ~20-30 seconds after it is broadcast and sometimes it is sooner than that. I expect to receive the broadcast immediately and not lag behind. Am i missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283440/broadcast-receiver-is-taking-too-long-to-receive-in-onreceive-after-airplane-m

Comment: If it is not required to send the broadcast system wide, then use local broadcasts:

`LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);` instead of  `context.sendBroadcast(intent);`

Comment: Adding FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND to intent solved it. Thanks!