# Starting Activity from background and hiding MainActivity - Popup Window

Tags: android, android-activity, service

I was wondering if it is possible to start Acitivty from service running in background and then move MainActivity to background.
I don't want to finish() MainActivity. Just hide it.

```
    Intent it=new Intent(context, NewPopupRecognizer.class);
    it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(it);
```

I tried this code but it is always starting Activity with delay.

I want to create popup Activity which i can turn on/off with floating button. I used to use WindowManger but it was very problematic so I decided to try doing it with Activity.

The popup should be like: Facebook Messenger or Google Assistant.

Answer (score 1):

I have read this in another post that this may help you:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(this, NewPopupRecognizer.class);
    intent.setComponent(cn);
    startActivity(intent);
```

found here [How to start an Activity from a Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456034/how-to-start-an-activity-from-a-)
service/3456099

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to send a [Broadcast](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html) to your activity from the service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.yourcompany.testIntent");
intent.putExtra("value","test");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Then your `MainActivity` picks it up and does:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.yourcompany.testIntent");
        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                  Intent it=new Intent(context, NewPopupRecognizer.class);
                  it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                  it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
                  startActivity(it);
            }
        };
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

You can add a mechanism that will open the activity directly from the service if the main activity is not there. For more options check out the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276537/using-a-broadcast-intent-broadcast-receiver-to-send-messages-from-a-service-to-a?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Comment: Works too but activity starts with delay.

Comment: How long is the delay? You can log and check, perhaps your service takes longer to react than you expect.

Comment: 3-4 seconds but only from background when mainactivity is on foreground everything is ok

Comment: Maybe You know other solution how to create popup?

Comment: Is it 3 seconds from when you get the initial trigger or from when you send the broadcast?

Comment: when i send broadcast

Comment: I think adding Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND flag may help (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283440/broadcast-receiver-is-taking-too-long-to-receive-in-onreceive-after-airplane-m)