# ListView in AppWidget doesnt show data from firebase

Tags: android, kotlin, listview, firebase-realtime-database, android-appwidget

I have an AppWidget with a ListView. When using a dummy arrayList `exampleData`, the ListView show the data of it. But when I try to retrieve data from firebase RD to `todayList`, my ListView doesn't show the data. When I check the size of `todayList` it's not 0 which means the data successfully retrieved by `todayList`. Can you help me?

**ListView when using `todayList`**

[image]

**ListView when using  dummy `exampleData`**

[image]

**This is my `ExampleWidgetItemFactory` class:**

```
internal class ExampleWidgetItemFactory(private val context: Context, intent: Intent) :
    RemoteViewsFactory {
    private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var preferences: Preferences
    private val mGoogleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient? = null
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var user: FirebaseUser

    private lateinit var userId: String
    private lateinit var userName:String

    private var todayList: ArrayList<Task> = arrayListOf()
    private val appWidgetId: Int
    private val exampleData = arrayListOf(
        "one", "two", "three", "four",
        "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"
    )

    override fun onCreate() {
        //connect to data source
        //Initialize
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        auth = Firebase.auth

        //User
        user = auth.currentUser
        userId = user.uid.toString()

        //Calendar
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1
        val day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        val date = String.format("%02d/%02d/%04d", day, month, year)

        database
                .child("users")
                .child(userId)
                .child("tasks")
                .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        //Hapus data dalam arraylist agar tidak jadi penumpukan data
                        todayList.clear()

                        //Ambil semua child dalam goal dan masukan ke items
                        var items = snapshot.children
                        //Lakukan iterasi pada setiap item lalu buat class dan tambahkan ke list
                        items.forEach {
                            var task = it.getValue(Task::class.java)
                            todayList.add(task!!)
                        }
                        Log.v("GAL", todayList.size.toString())
                        Log.v("GAL", todayList[0].title.toString())
                        SystemClock.sleep(3000)
                    }

                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                        TODO("Not yet implemented")
                    }

                })
    }

    override fun onDataSetChanged() {

    }
    override fun onDestroy() {
        //close data source
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return exampleData.size
    }

    override fun getViewAt(position: Int): RemoteViews {
        val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.example_widget_item)
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.example_widget_item_text, todayList[position].title)
        val fillIntent = Intent()
        fillIntent.putExtra(ExampleWidgetProvider().EXTRA_ITEM_POSITION, position)
        views.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.example_widget_item_text, fillIntent)
        SystemClock.sleep(500)
        return views
    }

    override fun getLoadingView(): RemoteViews? {
        return null
    }

    override fun getViewTypeCount(): Int {
        return 1
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    init {
        appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(
            AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
            AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID
        )
    }
}
```

**ExampleWidgetProvider  **

```
class ExampleWidgetProvider : AppWidgetProvider() {
    val ACTION_TOAST = "actionToast"
    val EXTRA_ITEM_POSITION = "extraItemPosition"

    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds)
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            val buttonIntent = Intent(context, HomeActivity::class.java)
            val buttonPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                0, buttonIntent, 0
            )
            val prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(
                ExampleAppWidgetConfig().SHARED_PREFS,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE
            )
            val buttonText = prefs.getString(
                ExampleAppWidgetConfig().KEY_BUTTON_TEXT + appWidgetId,
                "Press me"
            )
            val serviceIntent = Intent(context, ExampleWidgetService::class.java)
            serviceIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId)
            serviceIntent.data = Uri.parse(serviceIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME))

            val clickIntent =
                Intent(
                    context,ExampleWidgetProvider::class.java
                )
            clickIntent.action = ACTION_TOAST

            val clickPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                0, clickIntent, 0
            )

            val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.example_widget)
            views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.example_widget_stack_view, serviceIntent)
            views.setEmptyView(R.id.example_widget_stack_view, R.id.example_widget_empty_view)
            views.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.example_widget_stack_view, clickPendingIntent)
            
            val appWidgetOptions = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions(appWidgetId)
            resizeWidget(appWidgetOptions, views)
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
        }
    }

    override fun onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetId: Int,
        newOptions: Bundle
    ) {
        val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.example_widget)
        resizeWidget(newOptions, views)
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
    }

    private fun resizeWidget(appWidgetOptions: Bundle, views: RemoteViews) {
        val minWidth = appWidgetOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH)
        val maxWidth = appWidgetOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_WIDTH)
        val minHeight = appWidgetOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT)
        val maxHeight = appWidgetOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_HEIGHT)
    }

    override fun onDeleted(context: Context?, appWidgetIds: IntArray?) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "onDeleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onEnabled(context: Context?) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "onEnabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onDisabled(context: Context?) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "onDisabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
        if (ACTION_TOAST == intent.action) {
            val clickedPosition = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ITEM_POSITION, 0)
            Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked position: $clickedPosition", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        super.onReceive(context, intent)
    }

}

**When I try getting size and element in `todayList`:**

    Log.v("GAL", todayList.size.toString())
    Log.v("GAL", todayList[0].title.toString())

**The logcat result:**

    2021-04-15 11:57:41.554 8756-8756/com.giftech.taskmastertest V/GAL: 4
    2021-04-15 11:57:41.554 8756-8756/com.giftech.taskmastertest V/GAL: vv
```

Comment: This **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** might help.

Answer (score 1):

why do you think that your items should be shown on list? you are fetching items from database, fulfiling `todayList` in `forEach` and... thats all. you are never returning this `ArrayList` anywhere, especially it isn't set to some adapter, which is attached to `ListView`. looks like you have stripped to much code, post whole class - I bet your problem is related to async database reading, `onDataChange` is called later than drawing adapter/`ListView`, on the end of this method you should probably call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

edit: after posting whole class now all is clear: `RemoteViewsFactory` is producing views basing on data passed to this class, similar work as adapters does. this isn't a moment for fetching data from network, as this is async operation, and creating `RemoteViewsFactory` is kind-of sync way for fetching views for already existing items. you should fetch your data inside `extends AppWidgetProvider` class (in `onUpdate()` method), there may be a need for starting some `Service` for async data fetching and after storing whole array refresh widget GUI

Comment: in method below i was returning the todayList, ok ill edit it

Comment: how i can call `notifyDataSetChanged()` ? i have no idea how to do it. Can you give me an example?

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged` won't work in here sadly, app widget have own runtime and lifecycle, and `RemoteViewsFactory` is a class which is drawing your data, when it is created its too late for downloading data. check out my edit

Comment: oh okay, so all i have to do is redraw the data after the data is completely retrieved to list. But can u explain how to fetch inside the `onUpdate` method in `AppWidgetProvider ` ? hence it is on different class. I edit and add my `AppWidgetProvider `

Comment: `AppWidgetProvider` extends `BroadcastReceiver`, so you can wake it up by sending broadcast to it, as you do with `ACTION_TOAST`. introduce new action e.g. `ACTION_NEW_DATA`, place your database fetching code inside `onUpdate` and on the end of `onDataChange` send `new Intent` with this action and whole array in extras. inside `onReceive` detect this action and call `onUpdate` passing array from extras. in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304387/android-how-do-i-force-the-update-of-all-widgets-of-a-particular-kind) in answer (especially step 1) you have some sample